# application metadata has been modified out of the designer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-lightswitch

I was working to a lightswitch project in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio crashed and after restart of VS and Project when I try to add a table or a Screen to the project I retrieve following message:

*Changes have been made to project "name of project" and it needs to be reloaded before this action is taken. Would you like to reload the project now?*

I click yes, and after a while appear a Reload windows with following message:

*Application metadata has been modified out of the designer.
When you finish those changes, please use the "Reload" button to reload the desiner.*

Obviously if I use the Reload Button I get the same windows.

So I cannot work more on it.

Somebody have some tips of how can I solve it ?

Many thanks in advance

Piercarlo

Comment: in the past this happened to me when an application crashed, This is not a definitive answer which is why I haven't posted it below, but basically the last thing you were working on will have an underlying issue that cannot be solved, so usually by deleting that entire screen (rather annoying I know), but that fixed it for me and hopefully for you. Its worth taking a back up of the project first mind. its a process of elimination on deleting the parts you had open/were working on until the corrupt file is removed. Delete them within VS so it know there gone, then close it and open it up again